# OpenCV, adding an alpha mask to a cv::Mat gives strange results

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an alpha mask as a cv::Mat (1920 x 1080, CV_8UC3).

I am trying to use this to mask another solid colour cv::Mat object.

The relevant code is:

```
cv::Mat temp = cv::Mat::zeros(rows, cols, CV_8UC3);
temp.setTo(cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));          

temp.copyTo(outFrame, Matte);
```

The Matte frame looks like this:

[image]

However the resulting output looks like this:

[image]

Why might this be? Is there a more accurate way to apply a mask like this in opencv?

(I have loaded the matte as an image into after effects and checked it as a matte, and it looks good, so the actual image data is correct).

Comment: can you try `cv::imshow("actual mask",Matte>0);`? probably there are some addition<l non-zero pixels in your mask image. Depending on what you want to do, you should choose your mask to be Matte==200 or Matte > 100 or something like that. For adding an alpha channel you should cv::split your image, then push_back the mask and cv::merge it back to an image. Keep in mind that opencv typically doesnt use alpha channels, so if you want to test your alpha channel you should save the result to .png and open it in a viewer that uses/interprets alpha channel.

Comment: Hi, thank you. So i should be thresholding perhaps?  How can i keep the mask looking as i want it?

Comment: Yes, try thresholding your mask. Masks in opencv are 0 for inactive and everything else for active, so if there are low intensity pixels which you dont see with your eye the mask will not be what you expect it to be from looking at the intensity image. By thresholding you will make sure that the input is only 0 or 255 and you can debug it easier with your own eye.

Comment: Thank you! this: `cv::threshold(Matte, Matte, 20, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);` has cleaned it up nicely. :)

Comment: Maybe its better to answer your own question with an updated code.